# exe generated with py2exe can't find pywinauto

Tags: python, py2exe

I've been trying to pack my app with py2exe. The application works fine but it keeps failing to find/use pywinauto. I been googling but I get nothing,  I'm now I'm totally lost...

Here's the packing script:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
  windows = ["mainForm.py"],
  data_files=[
      ('', ['mainForm.ui']),
      ('', ['osk.sqlite'])
  ],
  options = {
              "py2exe":{
                        "optimize": 2,
                        "includes": [
                          'sip', 'pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com', 'xml.etree.ElementTree', 'sqlite3',
                          'pywinauto', 'pywinauto.application', 'pywinauto.controls', 'pywinauto.tests', 'SendKeys'
                            ],
                          "typelibs": [('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 0)]
                         }
              }
    )
```

And here's the ouput when running the exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainForm.py", line 129, in changeState
  File "mainForm.py", line 230, in setWriteMode
  File "mainForm.py", line 105, in FillApps
  File "WindowHandler.pyo", line 26, in getWindowList
NameError: global name 'pywinauto' is not defined
```

I hope anyone could point me into the right direct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need that many includes in your setup script... what do your imports look like in mainForm.py?

Comment: They go like this



<pre><code>
import sys
import Errors

try:
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
  import WordOps
  import Voice
  import WindowHandler
except Exception as e:
  Errors.Import("mainForm.py", e)
</code></pre>


The first line are includes needed for the app to work, the second line is my best trying to make the app work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, py2exe handles imports in a weird way.  Sometimes it has trouble finding linked-imports (like you import `WindowHandler`, which imports `pywinauto`).

I would start with this in **mainForm.py**:

```
import sys
import WordOps 
import Voice 
import WindowHandler
from PyQt import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

And in **setup.py**, start with this:

```
options={'py2exe':{
                    'includes': ['sip'],
                    'bundle_files': 1
                  }
        }
```

Make sure your program works before compiling to an exe, then try running setup.py.
When you start getting errors when running `setup.py` (like the one you posted), add more imports to **mainForm.py**.  So for that error, your new header will look like:

```
import sys
import WordOps 
import Voice 
import WindowHandler
from PyQt import QtCore, QtGui, uic
# imports for py2exe
import pywinauto
```

It will not break your code because it will just be an "unused" import.
Keep doing that until setup.py works.

Comment: I changed the imports and the options in the setup file, but now I get an error telling me that pywinauto\controls\win32_controls.pyc can't find win32functions. This lib is on pywinauto root folder. Now I'm importing it like this 'from pywinauto import win32functions'. Still not working.


Adding pywinauto to includes in setup has no effect.

Also py2exe generates a corrupted zip file when using "'bundle_files': 1"

Comment: You can remove bundle_files; try adding pywinauto to `packages` (another py2exe option) instead of `includes`. Also try adding pywinauto's dependencies too: `ctypes`, `SendKeys`, `PIL` and `elementtree`

Comment: Adding <code>packages:['pywinauto']</code> did the trick. Thanks A LOT for your help :)